# How to use Es in deutsch

Tags: question

> **"Ich musste mich beeilen, damit ich es dir nicht sagen konnte."**

Why this sentence is using es. Can I ignore the es here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, that sentence is illogical:

> <s>Ich musste mich beeilen, **damit** ich es dir nicht sagen konnte.</s>

I bet you translated from English:

*I had to hurry up, **so** I was unable to tell it to you.*

Though English *so* can be translated into German *damit* in a lot of cases, this isn't one of them. The reason is a clause led by *damit* is giving a reason, not a conclusion. **So** is ambivalent in both English and German:

> Ich musste mich beeilen, **so dass** ich es dir nicht sagen konnte.

If you want to mark the conclusion as such use:

> Ich musste mich beeilen, **weshalb/weswegen** ich es dir nicht sagen konnte.
>
> Ich musste mich beeilen, **daher/deshalb/deswegen** konnte ich es dir nicht sagen.

---

But you asked about the **es**. The reason you need it here is the verb *sagen* needs a **Prädikativ**, which is the thing said.

> Sie sagt nein.

*She says "no".*

> Er sagt viel, wenn der Tag lang ist.

*He says a lot when the day is long.*

> Er sagte es.

*He said it.*

If you leave the thing out, you are introducing indirect speech.

> Sie sagte, sie müsse jetzt gehen.

*She said she had to go now.*

Note the use of *Konjunktiv I* in the German indirect speech part.

---

So there has to be such a *Prädikativ*, either a thing said, **es** or an **Objektsatz**. If you leave it out completely, indirect speech has to follow:

> Ich musste mich beeilen, so dass ich **es** dir nicht sagen konnte.
>
> Ich musste mich beeilen, so dass ich dir nicht sagen konnte, **dass ich keine Zeit habe**.
>
> Ich musste mich beeilen, so dass ich dir nicht sagen konnte, **ich hätte keine Zeit.**

Comment: You are Awesome, Thanks for your hard work. Thank you very much.